# How to catch missing argument in function mistake?

Tags: linux, bash

I have just made the following mistake, where I am passing an argument to a function which is empty.

```
var1="ok"
var2=$notDefined

func $var1 $var2
func() {
  var1=$1
  var2=$2
  echo $var1
  echo $var2
}
```

For each argument in the function I could do

```
if [ -z $1 ]; then echo "Empty argument"; fi
```

But is there a more generic method to do this, so it is easy reusable, and would perhaps even tell the variable name that is empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stop whole script by `set -u`. It will fail if you try to use unset variable. It is very general approach.

Bash will output following localized message to standard error:

```
bash: x: unbound variable
```

Comment: @SandraSchlichting You can pipe script stderr to a file.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `?` bash variable substitution operator:

```
var1=${1:?"undefined!"}
```

If `$1` exists and isn't null, var1 is set to its value, otherwise bash prints `1` followed by `"undefined!"` and aborts the current command or script.  This syntax can used for any bash variable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the empty variables are created, because there are too few arguments to the function.
You can get the number of passed arguments via `$#`. All variables that use `$n` with a higher number `n` must then be empty. You could check for a sufficiently high number of arguments at the beginning of your function.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="ok"
var2=$notDefined

func() {
        if [[ $# -ge 2 ]];  then
                var1=$1
                var2=$2
                echo $var1
                echo $var2
        else
                echo "Missing values"
        fi
}
func $var1 $var2
```

Here it is running

```
./test.sh 
Missing values
```

Here it is with two values:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1="ok"
var2="dokie"

func() {
    if [[ $# -ge 2 ]];  then
        var1=$1
        var2=$2
        echo $var1
        echo $var2
    else
        echo "Missing values"
    fi
}
func $var1 $var2
```

Results with:

```
 ./test.sh 
ok
dokie
```